# How to understand the output?

Tags: c++, syntax

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try {
            char *p2 = NULL;
            cout << "p2:" << strlen(p2) <<endl; 
                    cout << "mark";
        }
        catch (...) {
            cout << "caught exception" <<endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `p2:`,so neither `cout << "mark";` nor `cout << "caught exception" <<endl;` got run,why?

Comment: Check pointers for NULL before using them!

Comment: @John Dibling: don't use pointers if NULL is not a valid option, use references instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, dereferencing a NULL pointer causes **undefined behavior**, which means anything could happen: the computer could blow up, the function could return an arbitrary value, the program could be killed by an operating system exception (which, unlike a C++ expression, cannot be caught with `try-catch`).

In short, **don't do it**.

If you really need to do this for an extremely good reason (like working around a bug in a library you have absolutely no control over), look into your operating system support for such things (such as [SEH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657%28VS.85%29.aspx) on Windows).

Answer (score 5):

On [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-compliant systems, your program receives the [SIGSEGV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV) signal and dies as soon as you call `strlen(p2)`, since `p2` is `NULL`.

To my knowledge, there's no way to portably catch [segfaults](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) using C++ exceptions.

Comment: SIGSEGV is POSIX specific. If you're not on a POSIX platform then this answer is wrong. The program exhibits undefined behavior according to the C++ standard and can therefore do whatever it wants. Some platforms, for example, do not have the concept of a segmentation fault (because a segfault is strictly an x86 concept)

Comment: And even getting "p2:" as output is not guaranteed, it could stay inside output stream buffer and never be printed.

Comment: @Billy, you're right, though I never encountered a platform for which `undefined behavior` did not manifest as the program getting a last chance to clean up before being forcibly terminated :)

Comment: It's not true that the program _will_ die, although it's a plausible outcome on many platforms. It causes _Undefined Behavior_, which might just as well return something seemingly correct.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: For this particular case if UB that would be true. However, UB in general means the compiler has complete latitude in specifying the behavior. More importantly "dying right on the spot" != "segmentation fault".

Comment: "because a segfault is strictly an x86 concept" Er, no. You get them on Vaxen, for instance (which I think is where the name originated)

Comment: @Paul: Okay, but it's definitely not something that exists on all hardware. ARM, for example, does not have the concept (because ARM never had "segments" to begin with). Same with MIPS and pretty much any other RISC architecture I can think of.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I agree some systems does not have segfault, but it's not an x86 concept. SEGV predates x86, and the concept exists on any system with hardware memory protection. Also the behavior of strlen if defined by C libraries and compiler have no word to say about the behavior of the program. It **must** call the function whose name is strlen providing it NULL as an input parameter. This function could be whatever the programming environment decides it to be, it can even be redefined for something completely different that the default one. No UB here.

Comment: @kriss: But the C standard defines passing a non-dereference-able pointer to `strlen` as undefined, so it's undefined behavior even if the function call is well defined.

Comment: "because ARM never had "segments" to begin with". It did in the early days (with the MMC) - I was at Acorn at the time. It'is not a RISC/CISC thing really either.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Yes, but as you do not have linking information nor headers, hence you can't know strlen() is the standard C function. It's just a guess.

Comment: @Paul: I was saying "RISC architectures of which I am aware", not "all RISC architectures". I never meant to imply that this was a RSIC vs. CISC issue.

Comment: Sure about that? SEGVs on ARM: http://www.riscos.info/index.php/RISC_OS_C_Programming_FAQ SEGV on PA RISC: http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-parisc/msg02015.html SEGV on MIPS http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CEkQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww-ug.eecg.utoronto.ca%2F~ece344%2Fassn%2FMIPS-Exploits.ppt&rct=j&q=risc%20segv%20mips&ei=ZgzcTNjaHY-5hAfcpIn-Dw&usg=AFQjCNGBWqs4XvMx7RGdPt2Nm5rZMQS0gA&sig2=jc2Ooec0eEuFzsQiiK5eKg&cad=rja

Comment: @Paul: You are linking to POSIX layers on top of the architectures themselves. More importantly, SEGV != Segmentation Fault. The name "Segmentation Fault" is what I'm referring to. Most every architecture has some form of interrupt that will be thrown, but not all architectures call it a "segmentation fault", particularly architectures which do not provide virtual memory facilities.

Comment: OK, I think now hairs are being split.  I'll leave it there.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has undefined behavior. Therefore **any** output or **no** output are both valid results. My guess is that `strlen` is causing an access violation (at least on x86) and your program is being terminated.

C++ does not throw exceptions upon trying to dereference a null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`strlen()` doesn't throw exceptions, because it's a C function and C does not have exceptions. It just crashes your program when you give it bad input. (Although it is not required to.)

Comment: It's a bit too strong to say C has no exceptions, especially in this context. Undefined Behavior in C allows all kinds of behavior, including throwing a (native) exception. For instance, on Windows the (undefined) behavior likely is an Access Violation Structured Exception.

Answer (score 0):

strlen(NULL) tries to dereference NULL pointer. This raises hardware exception which cannot be caught with try-catch mechanism. Program blows up. You would have the same scenario if you try to perform division by zero.

For this reason it is always a good practice to check whether pointers are (not) NULL. If pointer is NULL somewhere where it should not be (and you treat this as an exceptional situation), you can throw software exception from that place. Body of your catch block would have been executed If you had written something like this (before strlen call):

```
if(p2 == NULL)
    throw 1;
```

You forgot to add endl manipulator in line that prints "mark". It should be:

```
cout << "mark" << endl;
```